# How to draw several lines of the graph in Qt using QCustomPlot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcustomplot

For example, in Visual Studio there is tChart and its Series property, which is responsible for drawing lines of the graph. Here is an example of this code

```
for (int j = 1; j < Nt - 1; j++)
  {
   for (int i = 1; i < Nt - 1; i++)
    {
       chart2->Series["" + (j + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(i, wht[j][i]);
    }
  }
```

And draw this graph with a lot of lines.

[image]

But my task is transfering in `Qt Creator`(because in `Qt Creator` may making a lot of opportunities)
This code

```
void MainWindow::drawdifnet(int Nt)
{
    int N=Nt;
    int N1=pow(N,2);
    QVector<double> x22(N), y22(N1); 
    int ii=0,jj=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < Nt ; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Nt ; i++)
                {          
                    x22[jj]=i;
                    y22[ii]=wht[j][i];
                    ui->widget_2->addGraph();
                    ui->widget_2->graph(0)->setData(x22,y22);
                  ii++;
                }
                jj++;
    }
    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setLabel("OsX");
    ui->widget_2->yAxis->setLabel("OsY");
    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setRange(30,30);
    ui->widget_2->replot();
}
```

Doesn't work correctly.
Result is the empty widget

In first I with help debugger check the `QVectors` data
In this pictures see that my dinamic array `wht[j][i]` in work and loaded in QVector `yy[ii]`

[image]
[image]

I think the problem in the loop.

In QtCustomPlot tutorial this problem solving this code

```
ui->widget_2->graph(0)->setData(x,y);
ui->widget_2->graph(1)->setData(x11,y11);
ui->widget_2->graph(2)->setData(x22,y22);
```

But in my situation  the quantity of lines is know when the program working.

How I create and assigned my array

```
void created(int Nt, int Nx) ///This function creating my dynamic array
{
    wht = new double *[Nt];
    for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
        wht[i] = new double[Nx];
}

inline double fn(int T, double x) ///these 4 functions for my mathematical part(works good)
{
    if (x >= 0)
        return T;
    return 0;
}

inline double u0(int T, double x)
{
    return fn(T, x);
}

inline double u1(int T, double a, int xmin, double t)
{
    return fn(T, xmin - a * t);
}

inline double u2(int T, double a, int xmax, double t)
{
    return fn(T, xmax - a * t);
}


void calculatedifnet(int xmin, double hx, double ht, double a, int Nx, int Nt, int T)
//These main function.We have the empty array and in this function we fill array. Then we solve in the main loop and the fill the first indexes wht[j]
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
    {
        wht[0][i] = u0(T, xmin + i*hx);//fill the second indexeswht[null][i]
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < Nt - 1; j++)//the calculated code(works right).The result writing in wht[j]
    {
        wht[j + 1][0] = u1(T, a, xmin, j*ht);
        for (int i = 1; i < Nt; i++)
        {
            double dudx = (wht[j][i] - wht[j][i - 1]) / hx;
            wht[j + 1][i] = -a * dudx * ht + wht[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why one of your vector is size N and the other N**2=NxN?

Comment: Becase the ln iteration `j` calculate 12 points.

Every step `j` includes 12 steps calculation the coordinates.
`12 graphs = 12 points ` in every graphs  and so there are a different sizes.

Comment: What is the data type of wht?

Comment: @eyllanesc wht dinamic array of double

Comment: Could you show how you have declared and assigned it?

Comment: When you place `wht[j][i]`, I understand it's an array of doubles array, it's different from doubles array.

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited my header information and added code where array create and assigned

Comment: I suppose Nx is greater than Nt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there are the following errors:

- If we observe x is a constant vector from `0` to `Nt-1`, then we only have to create it once:

---

```
QVector<double> x(Nt);
for (int i = 0; i < Nt ; i++)
    x[i]=i;//0 to Nt-1
```

- [`addGraph()`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCustomPlot.html#a6fb2873d35a8a8089842d81a70a54167) adds a graph and places it in the last position, if you want to graph you must access by the last index, not by the index 0:

---

```
ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(xx, yy);
```

- Assuming that `wht` is of type `QVector<QVector<double>>`  and of size `NtxNt`, then is not necessary to access each element, we can access each `QVector<double>` since the function [`setData()`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html#a73578d786532132310a926c3cd529b29) accepts as input this type of data. To the function [`setData()`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html#a73578d786532132310a926c3cd529b29) you must pass 2 vectors of the same size, but you were passing 2 vectors of `Nt` and `Nt*Nt`, this generated a warning:

---

```
ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(x, wht[j]);
```

- [`setRange()`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPAxis.html#a57d6ee9e9009fe88cb19db476ec70bca) places the range from a to b, but if they are the same QCustomPlot will never fit the range, for my test I set it as follows:

---

```
ui->widget_2->xAxis->setRange(0,Nt);
ui->widget_2->yAxis->setRange(0,Nt*Nt);
```

In short the code would be as follows:

```
void MainWindow::drawdifnet(int Nt){

    QVector<double> x(Nt);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nt ; i++)
        x[i]=i;//0 to Nt-1

    for (int j = 0; j < Nt ; j++)
        ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(x, wht[j]);

    /* if c++11
    for (auto& row: wht)
        ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(x, row);
    */

    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setLabel("OsX");
    ui->widget_2->yAxis->setLabel("OsY");
    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setRange(0,Nt);
    ui->widget_2->yAxis->setRange(0,Nt*Nt);
    ui->widget_2->replot();

}
```

Output:

[image]

*Note: For the test `wht[i][j] = i*j`*

In your case `wht` is a variable of type `double**`, also assume that `Nx>=Nt`, for this you must use the following code:

```
void MainWindow::drawdifnet(int Nt)
{
    QVector<double> x(Nt);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nt ; i++){
        x[i]=i;//0 to Nt-1
    }

    QVector<double> y(Nt);
    for(int i=0; i<Nt; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<Nt; j++){
            y[j] = wht[i][j];
        }
        ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(x, y);
    }

    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setLabel("OsX");
    ui->widget_2->yAxis->setLabel("OsY");
    ui->widget_2->xAxis->setRange(0,12);
    ui->widget_2->yAxis->setRange(0,3.5);
    ui->widget_2->replot();
}
```

Input:

- created(12, 12);
- calculatedifnet(1, .5, .5, 0.9, 12, 12, 3);

Output:

[image]

Comment: In this code error

`ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(x, wht[j]);`

`no matching function for call to 'QCPGraph::setData(QVector<double>&, double*&)' ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(x, wht[j]);       `

Comment: Note: For the test wht[i][j] = i*j

it means that I write ui->widget_2->addGraph()->setData(x, i*j);